# How to get RecyclerView Edit Text values?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` with `EditText`. I am manually adding items to `RecyclerView` by searching and each row has a `EditText`  and some `TextViews`.  I know how to get `TextView` data, but the problem is to get `EditText` input data(number values). I can get first 5 edit text data (first 5 rows) but from the 5th position it gave me the 5th position `EditText` value.

```
Item : 7.50-15 10PR FM CEAT               Quantity : 1
Item : 5.60-15 04PR K 511 CEAT            Quantity : 2
Item : 2.75-18 04PR SECURA F85 CEAT (F)   Quantity : 3
Item : 3.00-17 06PR SECURA ZOOM CEAT (R)  Quantity : 4
Item : 6.50-14 10PR FM CEAT               Quantity : 5
Item : 5.00-12 04PR GRIP MASTER CEAT      Quantity : 5
Item : 4.00-08 06PR AUTO RAJA RPG         Quantity : 5
Item : 9.00-20 14PR CEAT CLT LUG          Quantity : 5
Item : 8.25-20 14PR TR PLUS SUNTRAC       Quantity : 5
Item : 7.00-15 12PR FM CEAT               Quantity : 5
```

I am using this method from main activity to get edit text data. I am using for loop.

```
private String getNumPicNumber(int i) {
        if (myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i) instanceof SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder) {
            SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder childHolder = (SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder) myRecyclerView.findViewHolderForLayoutPosition(i);
            numberPickerNumber = childHolder.getQtyNumber();
        }
        return numberPickerNumber;
    }
```

This is my adapter.

```
public class SelectItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder> {

    private List<String> itemsName, itemsQty, itemsPCode, itemPlant;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    //private List<DummyEntry> mDataset;
    private String[] mDataset;
    public ArrayList myItems = new ArrayList();

    public SelectItemAdapter(Context context, String[] mDataset) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        itemsName = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsQty = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsPCode = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemPlant = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.mDataset = mDataset;


    }


    @Override
    public SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_selected_item, parent, false);
        return new ItemHolder(itemView, this, new MyCustomEditTextListener());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SelectItemAdapter.ItemHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));
        holder.setItemQty(itemsQty.get(position));
        holder.setItemPCode(itemsPCode.get(position));
        holder.setItemPlant(itemPlant.get(position));

        holder.myCustomEditTextListener.updatePosition(position);
        holder.numPicker.setText(mDataset[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsName.size();
    }

    public Object getItemName(int position) {
        return itemsName.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemPCode(int position) {
        return itemsPCode.get(position);
    }

    public Object getItemPlant(int position) {
        return itemPlant.get(position);
    }


    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        onItemClickListener = listener;
    }

    public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener() {
        return onItemClickListener;
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
    }

    public void add(int location, String iName, String iQty, String iPCode, String iPlant) {
        itemsName.add(location, iName);
        itemsQty.add(location, iQty);
        itemsPCode.add(location, iPCode);
        itemPlant.add(location, iPlant);
        notifyItemInserted(location);
    }

    public void remove(int location) {
        if (location >= itemsName.size())
            return;

        itemsName.remove(location);
        notifyItemRemoved(location);
    }

    public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private SelectItemAdapter parent;
        TextView textItemName, txtPCode, txtAvailableQty, txtTempQty, txtPlant;
        Button bRemove;
        EditText numPicker;
        public MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener;

        public ItemHolder(View itemView, SelectItemAdapter parent, MyCustomEditTextListener myCustomEditTextListener) {
            super(itemView);
            this.parent = parent;
            textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
            txtAvailableQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtAvailbleQty);
            txtPCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPCode);
            txtPlant = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPlant);
            bRemove = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bRemove);
            numPicker = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
            this.myCustomEditTextListener = myCustomEditTextListener;
            this.numPicker.addTextChangedListener(myCustomEditTextListener);
            bRemove.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        public void setItemName(CharSequence name) {
            textItemName.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemQty(CharSequence name) {
            txtAvailableQty.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemPCode(CharSequence name) {
            txtPCode.setText(name);
        }

        public void setItemPlant(CharSequence name) {
            txtPlant.setText(name);
        }

        public String getQtyNumber() {
            return numPicker.getText().toString();
        }

        public CharSequence getItemName() {
            return textItemName.getText();
        }


        public CharSequence getItemPCode() {
            return txtPCode.getText();
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyCustomEditTextListener implements TextWatcher{

        private int position;

        public void updatePosition(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }


        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            mDataset[position] = charSequence.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get all edit text data? Only showing values are coming in the screen.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a problem with trying to call a recyclerview cell that isn't displayed and its just recycling the value of the previous cell. Try having the edit texts actually change the dataset and get your information from the changed dataset insead.

Comment: How do i get values from changed dataset?